# Colors for terminal with curl in docker container

Tags: node.js, npm, curl, terminal, dockerfile

I have a very simple Node.js app:

```
import terminalImage from 'terminal-image';
import express from 'express';

const app = express();

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
    res.send(await terminalImage.file('image.png', {width: 85, height: 45, preserveAspectRatio: false}));
});

app.listen(80);
```

Which works just fine in my Windows if I send post request using curl to localhost:80. But if I run the same app as docker container on my server, the image has no colors, just white squares. The Dockerfile im using:

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install

COPY . .

EXPOSE 80

CMD [ "node", "app.mjs" ]
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After adding the -it flag everything now working!

```
docker run -d -it -p 80:80 --name CurlImageApp curlimageapp:latest
```